# Setting Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created the project using the path below
file>new>new project>settings activity.

a page comes up when the application is opened and the second page opens when I click to text.
page 1
[image: page1]
page 2
[image: page2]
how can I open page 2 when the application is opened?

my code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import java.util.List;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for clarification: do you want the application to launch on the `SettingsActivity`?

Comment: my app still launch on the settingsActivity but I want to open page 2 without any click. please check page 1 and page 2 image. my app should launch on page 2. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do you want to open the page1 or page 2 when your application opens

Comment: @michaelzX u want page2 should open on app launch...or after launch you want to go on page 2 without click?

Comment: I solved my problem. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open it when you start the application in the onCreate method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                           //Change layout_name to your xml/layout
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
```

Is there some reason this why this approach won't work for you?

Comment: there is no second activity. I can upload my project to github if you want.

Comment: wow I tried it before but it didn't work but I deleted some code and now it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create create a SplashActivity and launch your first page with specific parameter that will cause it to launch the second page

SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent( this, SettingsActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra( PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, SettingsActivity.DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName() );
    intent.putExtra( PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, true );
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

you should also modify your manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.maxim.testsettings">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```